# Swift 2: Populating a TableView with two CoreData entities

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift2

This is my second question here on the site so any feedback is appreciated in regards to question format. With that being said here's my problem:

I'm trying to populate this tableview with two different CoreData entities and I don't know how to go about that. At first I tried creating another object and doing the necessary methods for the tableview but it didn't work. I'm trying to populate it with data from another entity and I can't get the tableview to display information from the second entity. I'm wondering if there are any known conventions for doing this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataEntryTableViewController: UITableViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet var listaMiembros: UITableView!

var object = [NSManagedObject]()

var dictionary: [String:String] = [
    "tipoVehiculo" :"",
    "ocupantes" :"",
    "numDeTablilla" :"",
    "jurisdiccion": "",
    "estado" :"",
    "vin" :"",
    "year" :"",
    "marca": "",
    "model" :"",
    "marbete" :"",
    "aseguradora" :"",
    "fechaCompra": "",
    "fechaExpiracion": "",
   ]

var objectNum = -1

@IBOutlet weak var listaMembers: UITableViewCell!
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()
  listaMiembros.delegate = self
  listaMiembros.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //ADD SCROLL VIEW DIMENTIONS

    if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
      //  menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
           menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2       
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PageFour")

    //3
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        object = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    objectNum = -1
 }

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return object.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    let person = object[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel!.text = person.valueForKey("numDeTablilla") as? String
   return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow // index path of selected cell

    let cellIndex = indexPath!.row // index of selected cell
    // print(indexPath?.row)//iT'S THE NUMBER YOU WANT - 1
    let cellName = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) //  instance of selected cell
    objectNum = cellIndex + 1
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PageFour")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("There was a problem!")
    }

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                if cellName?.textLabel?.text == result.valueForKey("numDeTablilla") as? String{

                    dictionary["numDeTablilla"] = result.valueForKey("numDeTablilla") as? String
                    dictionary["marca"] = result.valueForKey("marcaField") as? String
                    dictionary["model"] = result.valueForKey("modeloField") as? String
                    dictionary["year"] = result.valueForKey("yearField") as? String
                    dictionary["tipoVehiculo"] = result.valueForKey("tipoVehiculo") as? String
                    dictionary["ocupantes"] = result.valueForKey("ocupantes") as? String
                    dictionary["jurisdiccion"] = result.valueForKey("jurisdicionVehiculo") as? String
                    dictionary["estado"] = result.valueForKey("estadoField") as? String
                    dictionary["vin"] = result.valueForKey("vinField") as? String
                    dictionary["marbete"] = result.valueForKey("numeroDeMarbete") as? String
                    dictionary["aseguradora"] = result.valueForKey("aseguradoraField") as? String
                    dictionary["fechaCompra"] = result.valueForKey("fechaCompraField") as? String
                    dictionary["fechaExpiracion"] = result.valueForKey("FechaExpiracionField") as? String

                }
            }
            performSegueWithIdentifier("EditVehicle", sender: self)
        }

    } catch {
        print("Fetch Failed")
    }
}

 @IBAction func unwindToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EditVehicle"){
        //prepare for segue to the details view controller

        if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NewVehicleController {
            // let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

            detailsVC.dictionary = self.dictionary
            detailsVC.objectNum = self.objectNum
        }
    }
    //unnecessary for now
//        if(segue.identifier == "gotoNewData"){
//            if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as?         NewDataEntryTableViewController {
//                //detailsVC.dictionary = self.dictionary
//                detailsVC.objectNum = self.objectNum
//            }
//        }
    self.tableView.reloadData()    
}  
}
```

Comment: so what is the exact problem?

Comment: Can you add an image showing what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I added it to the question but I'm gonna mention it here as well. I wanna populate the tableview with information from a second entity but it won't work and I don't know how to tackle the problem.

Comment: where is the code part that performs a fetching request for the second entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't retain managedObjects.  If the object is deleted from the database accessing it will cause a crash.  It it is better to use a `fetchedResultsController` that automatically tracks inserts, deletions and changes.

The easiest solution for your problem is to have entities of one type in one section and entities of another type in a different section. (You needn't have a section header so it can appear as one section).  You have to have two different `fetchedResultsController` - one for each section. And you have to be careful to convert your tableview indexPath to the correct fetchedResultsController indexPath - but if you only have two section it is not that hard.

If you want the different entities intersperse between each other that is **much** harder but it is possible.

Also, I don't know why you are doing a fetch in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that seems wrong. If the data is related to the managedObject at that indexPath you should be able to get any data you need via a relationship.

Comment: I'll just add for "entities intersperse between each other": If possible create a parent entity for these and make sure that in your core data model they all inherit from this entity (there is a property to set a parent entity in the core data IB). Then simply create a fetch request on the parent and you will get the combination of both tables.

Comment: This is the information I was looking for. I'll get on it and post updates asap. Thanks for the help Jon and Matic!

Comment: I was wondering if maybe I could just manually add a cell with title equal to the field I want from the coredata entity. Is that possible? If so how would I add the cell?

Comment: Just providing an update. I did do as per your advice and use two fetcched results controllers and assigned each to a section.